# Solution of integrals as Hyperbolic functions

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

The solution of
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} \pm a^{2}}}\, \operatorname{d}x
$$
is $\ln\left( x+ \sqrt{x^{2} \pm a^{2}} \right)$. Can this be represented in hyperbolic form as $\sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{a} \right)$ and $-\cosh^{-1}\left( -\frac{x}{a} \right)$ respectively for positive and negative?

Comment: Try writing your question using MathJax

Comment: Sorry for not posting in Latex. Couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: How to do so? I tried for a really long time but didn’t get it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  .

Comment: your welcome @SidN

Comment: $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\sinh^{-1}\frac xa,\>\>\>\>\>
 \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\sinh^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-\frac1{x^2}}\right)
$$

Comment: @Quanto You should write an answer.